# Exoplayer unable to play DASH video android

Tags: android, mpeg-dash, exoplayer

I'm trying to play DASH video with the help of `Uri` obtained from `exoplayer` demo app https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/assets/media.exolist.json

When I change my network from WIFI to mobile data , video quality doesn't change instead it starts buffering.

**My code**

```
private void initializePlayer() {
        if (player == null) {

            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                    new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                    new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());

            exoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

            player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
            player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
        }


        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/3aa39fa2cc27967f/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=A2716F75795F5D2AF0E88962FFCD10DB79384F29.84308FF04844498CE6FBCE4731507882B8307798&key=ik0");
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);

        player.addListener(new PlayerEventListener());
        player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
        //exoPlayerView.setUseController(false);

    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
        DataSource.Factory manifestDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua");
        DashChunkSource.Factory dashChunkSourceFactory = new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua", BANDWIDTH_METER));
        return new DashMediaSource.Factory(dashChunkSourceFactory, manifestDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
    }
```

**gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.7.0'
```

**Is there Anything I missed ?**

Comment: "video quality doesn't change instead it starts buffering" but the video is still playing?

Comment: yes ... it tries to buffer high quality videos even in low network , where DASH failed

Comment: try this url : "http://www.bok.net/dash/tears_of_steel/cleartext/stream.mpd"

Comment: I soved it  .. have  look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake

instead of `new DefaultTrackSelector()`

I used

```
TrackSelection.Factory adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory =
                    new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);

new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory)
```